# ggplot2 tag position not centered

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a tag for each plot, ideally the tag should be placed at top and at the center position of the x-axis, here is the example:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars) +
  ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(mpg, wt)) +
  ggplot2::geom_smooth(ggplot2::aes(mpg, wt)) +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, " very very long label")) +
  ggplot2::labs(tag = "A", x = "mpg", y = "wt") +
  ggplot2::theme(plot.tag.position = "top")
```

The out put looks like this:
[image]

I notice that when the y axis labels are very long, the tag appears to be at the center of the whole panel, but not the center of the x axis. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you won't be using facets mapped to data, you can make a fake facet with a fixed value, and style it using the `strip.background` `theme` element:

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, " very very long label")) +
  facet_wrap(~ "A") +
  labs(x = "mpg", y = "wt") +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

Probably a better option is to add a secondary x axis with no labels nor breaks, and remove the line with by setting the `axis.line.x.top` on the `theme` to `element_blank()`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, " very very long label")) +
  ###
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "A", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL)) +
  ###
  labs(x = "mpg", y = "wt") +
  theme(axis.line.x.top = element_blank())
```

Comment: That's smart! But by this approach can we add a fake facet strip with special characters or math notations? I tried `ggplot2::facet_wrap(~ parse(text = difference_var_to_label(i)))`  which converts `i` to an expression, but no luck, I got an error ``x` must be a vector, not an expression vector.`

Comment: And by your second approach, I think you might need to hide the line of the second x axis

Comment: What does the `difference_var_to_label` function do, and what is `i` in your expression? Is it in the data?

Comment: Edited to remove the axis line. It is white with the default theme, that's why I didn't see it in the first place.

Comment: `i` is in an outer loop for plotting each panel, which is a string, and `difference_var_to_label` converts `i` into another string. For example, `i` is `lambda1`, the output of `difference_var_to_label(i)` is `lambda[italic(1)]`

Comment: You need to specify `labeller=label_parsed` to the `facet_` function, e.g.: `facet_wrap(~"x^a", labeller = label_parsed)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256421/discussion-between-tianjian-qin-and-ze-loff).

Comment: Worth noting that second axis is still unavailavble without hack for the discrete and categorical scales in ggplot2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way using `plot.margin` in `theme` to create more space at the top of the plot (t = 40). With the `annotate` function we place the label `A` at the top.
With the `y = Inf` and `vjust = -1.5` we move the label at the top to the extra margin space, for this we also need to use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")` which "allows" the annotation to be placed outside the plot area.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, " very very long label")) +
  labs(x = "mpg", y = "wt") +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(t = 40, r = 10, b = 10, l = 10)  
  ) +
  annotate("text", x = mean(range(mtcars$mpg)), y = Inf, label = "A", vjust = -1.5) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]