# Problem creating fake facet strips in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

Due to some reasons I could not use the facet feature in my real data. I have to plot every facet manually and then give each facet a strip. I was using `labs(tag = "something")` but the tags look less nice than facet strips. Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77731360/9038562) I try to fake facet strips , by the example code:

```r
p_list <- list()
for (i in c("lambda","mu","alpha","phi")) {
  p_list[[length(p_list) + 1]] <- ggplot2::ggplot(mtcars) +
    ggplot2::geom_point(ggplot2::aes(mpg, wt)) +
    ggplot2::geom_smooth(ggplot2::aes(mpg, wt)) +
    ggplot2::facet_wrap(~ eval(i), labeller = ggplot2::label_parsed) +
    ggplot2::labs(x = i, y = i)
}
patchwork::wrap_plots(plotlist = p_list)
```

Plot:

[image]

The problem is that all the fake facet strips are the same as the last one, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to create a function that builds the plot and then using `lapply` to iterate over the arguments (or `mapply`, if you want to iterate over multiple vectors), creating the plot list, that is then passed to `wrap_plots`:

```r
build_plot <- function(i) {
  ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(mpg, wt)) +
  facet_wrap(~ eval(i), labeller = ggplot2::label_parsed) +
  labs(x = i, y = i)
}
patchwork::wrap_plots(plotlist = lapply(c("lambda","mu","alpha","phi"), build_plot))
```

This would all be a lot simpler if you could just add a column to the `data.frame` with the label (even if it means repeating the data) and then using that column to define the facets.

Comment: Creating a new column might not be efficient especially when my real data is extremely large, IMO creating tags/strips dynamically could save a lot of memory space